# How to make by button invisible till clicked

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I am creating a windows 8 app of which I have a scroll bar and a button. When the page is launched I want the button to be invisible until the scroll bar is touched. I make the button invisible with this line of code.

```
ContinueButton.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

however when i go into the slider change part of my code and maake the visibility of the button visible it does not work. The button becomes visible even before the slider is touched. What am i doing wrong. Below is the part of code concerned.

```
  using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using Ward_Obs_Roaming.Common;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

// The User Control item template is documented at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=234236

namespace Ward_Obs_Roaming.UI.ObsUserControls
{
    public sealed partial class TemperatureObsControl : UserControl
    {
        public string ObsIndicatorImage
        {
            get
            {
                if (IndicatorImage.Source != null)
                    return (IndicatorImage.Source as BitmapImage).UriSource.ToString();
                else
                    return string.Empty;
            }
        }

        public string MEWSScore
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        private string _Note = string.Empty;
        public string Note
        {
            get { return _Note; }
            set { _Note = value; }
        }

        public string TemperatureColor
        {
            get { return (TemperatureGrid.Background as SolidColorBrush).Color.ToString(); }
            set
            {
                byte A = Byte.Parse(value.Substring(1, 2));
                byte R = Byte.Parse(value.Substring(3, 2));
                byte G = Byte.Parse(value.Substring(5, 2));
                byte B = Byte.Parse(value.Substring(7, 2));
                TemperatureGrid.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(A, R, G, B));
            }
        }

        public string TemperatureResult
        {
            //get { return DegreesComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString() + DecimalComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString(); }
            //set//getting data as x.y...split and set combo box items
            //{
            //    string[] splitTemperature = value.Split('.');
            //    DegreesComboBox.SelectedItem = splitTemperature[0];
            //    DecimalComboBox.SelectedItem = "." + splitTemperature[1];
            //}

            get
            {
                return TemperatureSlider.Value.ToString("##.#") + "°c";
            }
            set
            {
                value = value.Replace("°c", string.Empty);
                TemperatureSlider.Value = Double.Parse(value.ToString());
            }
        }

        public Button TemperatureContinueButton
        {
            get
            {
                return ContinueButton;
            }
        }

        public TemperatureObsControl()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            TemperatureSlider.ValueChanged += TemperatureSlider_ValueChanged;
            TemperatureSlider.Value = 37;
            ContinueButton.Content = "No Change";
            ContinueButton.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

        void TemperatureSlider_ValueChanged(object sender, RangeBaseValueChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ContinueButton.Content = "Update";
            ContinueButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            TemperatureTextBlock.Text = TemperatureSlider.Value.ToString("##.#") + "°c";

            TemperatureTextBlock.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
            MEWSScoreLabel.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
            MEWSScoreTextBlock.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);

            //int bloodOxygenLevel = Int32.Parse(BloodOxygenSlider.Value.ToString());
            double temperature = TemperatureSlider.Value;

            switch (CommonVariables.ObsCategory)
            {
                case ObsCategories.NormalObs:
                    {
                        //if (CommonVariables.is_Abnormal && CommonVariables.abnormal.temperature != null)
                        //{
                        //    if (temperature <= double.Parse(CommonVariables.abnormal.temperature.ElementAt<string>(0).Split(';').ElementAt<string>(1)))
                        //    {
                        //        TemperatureGrid.Background = (Application.Current as App).Resources["RedObsBrush"] as SolidColorBrush;
                        //        IndicatorImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Images/exclamationMark.png"));
                        //        MEWSScore = "3";
                        //    }
                        //    else if (temperature <= double.Parse(CommonVariables.abnormal.temperature.ElementAt<string>(1).Split(';').ElementAt<string>(1)))
                        //    {
                        //        TemperatureGrid.Background = (Application.Current as App).Resources["AmberObsBrush"] as SolidColorBrush;
                        //        IndicatorImage.Source = null;
                        //        MEWSScore = "2";
                        //    }
                        //    else if (temperature <= double.Parse(CommonVariables.abnormal.temperature.ElementAt<string>(2).Split(';').ElementAt<string>(1)))
                        //    {
                        //        TemperatureGrid.Background = (Application.Current as App).Resources["YellowObsBrush"] as SolidColorBrush;
                        //        IndicatorImage.Source = null;
                        //        MEWSScore = "1";
                        //        TemperatureTextBlock.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
                        //        MEWSScoreLabel.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
                        //        MEWSScoreTextBlock.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
                        //    }
                        //    else if (temperature <= double.Parse(CommonVariables.abnormal.temperature.ElementAt<string>(3).Split(';').ElementAt<string>(1)))
                        //    {
                        //        TemperatureGrid.Background = (Application.Current as App).Resources["GreenObsBrush"] as SolidColorBrush;
                        //        IndicatorImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Images/tickMark.png"));
                        //        MEWSScore = "0";
                        //    }
                        //    else if (temperature <= double.Parse(CommonVariables.abnormal.temperature.ElementAt<string>(4).Split(';').ElementAt<string>(1)))
                        //    {
                        //        TemperatureGrid.Background = (Application.Current as App).Resources["GreenObsBrush"] as SolidColorBrush;
                        //        IndicatorImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Images/tickMark.png"));
                        //        MEWSScore = "0";
                        //    }
                        //    else if (temperature <= double.Parse(CommonVariables.abnormal.temperature.ElementAt<string>(5).Split(';').ElementAt<string>(1)))
                        //    {
                        //        TemperatureGrid.Background = (Application.Current as App).Resources["YellowObsBrush"] as SolidColorBrush;
                        //        IndicatorImage.Source = null;
                        //        MEWSScore = "1";
                        //        TemperatureTextBlock.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
                        //        MEWSScoreLabel.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
                        //        MEWSScoreTextBlock.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
                        //    }
                        //    else
                        //    {
                        //        TemperatureGrid.Background = (Application.Current as App).Resources["AmberObsBrush"] as SolidColorBrush;
                        //        IndicatorImage.Source = null;
                        //        MEWSScore = "2";
                        //    }
                        //}
                        if (CommonVariables.is_Abnormal && CommonVariables.abnormal.temperature != null)
                        {
                            if (temperature <= double.Parse(CommonVariables.abnormal.temperature.ElementAt<string>(0).Split(';').ElementAt<string>(1)))
                            {
                                TemperatureGrid.Background = (Application.Current as App).Resources["RedObsBrush"] as SolidColorBrush;
                                IndicatorImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Images/exclamationMark.png"));
                                MEWSScore = "3";
                            }
                            else if (temperature <= double.Parse(CommonVariables.abnormal.temperature.ElementAt<string>(1).Split(';').ElementAt<string>(1)))
                            {
                                TemperatureGrid.Background = (Application.Current as App).Resources["AmberObsBrush"] as SolidColorBrush;
                                IndicatorImage.Source = null;
                                MEWSScore = "2";
                            }
                            else if (temperature <= double.Parse(CommonVariables.abnormal.temperature.ElementAt<string>(2).Split(';').ElementAt<string>(1)))
                            {
                                TemperatureGrid.Background = (Application.Current as App).Resources["YellowObsBrush"] as SolidColorBrush;
                                IndicatorImage.Source = null;
                                MEWSScore = "1";
                                TemperatureTextBlock.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
                                MEWSScoreLabel.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
                                MEWSScoreTextBlock.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
                            }
                            else if (temperature <= double.Parse(CommonVariables.abnormal.temperature.ElementAt<string>(3).Split(';').ElementAt<string>(1)))
                            {
                                TemperatureGrid.Background = (Application.Current as App).Resources["GreenObsBrush"] as SolidColorBrush;
                                IndicatorImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Images/tickMark.png"));
                                MEWSScore = "0";
                            }
                            else if (temperature <= double.Parse(CommonVariables.abnormal.temperature.ElementAt<string>(4).Split(';').ElementAt<string>(1)))
                            {
                                TemperatureGrid.Background = (Application.Current as App).Resources["YellowObsBrush"] as SolidColorBrush;
                                IndicatorImage.Source = null;
                                MEWSScore = "1";
                                TemperatureTextBlock.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
                                MEWSScoreLabel.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
                                MEWSScoreTextBlock.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                TemperatureGrid.Background = (Application.Current as App).Resources["AmberObsBrush"] as SolidColorBrush;
                                IndicatorImage.Source = null;
                                MEWSScore = "2";
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {

                            if (temperature <= 34)//<=34
                            {
                                TemperatureGrid.Background = (Application.Current as App).Resources["RedObsBrush"] as SolidColorBrush;
                                IndicatorImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Images/exclamationMark.png"));
                                MEWSScore = "3";
                            }
                            else if (temperature <= 35)//34-35
                            {
                                TemperatureGrid.Background = (Application.Current as App).Resources["AmberObsBrush"] as SolidColorBrush;
                                IndicatorImage.Source = null;
                                MEWSScore = "2";
                            }
                            else if (temperature <= 36)//35-36
                            {
                                TemperatureGrid.Background = (Application.Current as App).Resources["YellowObsBrush"] as SolidColorBrush;
                                IndicatorImage.Source = null;
                                MEWSScore = "1";
                                TemperatureTextBlock.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
                                MEWSScoreLabel.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
                                MEWSScoreTextBlock.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
                            }
                            else if (temperature <= 37)//36-37
                            {
                                TemperatureGrid.Background = (Application.Current as App).Resources["GreenObsBrush"] as SolidColorBrush;
                                IndicatorImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Images/tickMark.png"));
                                MEWSScore = "0";
                            }
                            else if (temperature <= 38)//37-38
                            {
                                TemperatureGrid.Background = (Application.Current as App).Resources["GreenObsBrush"] as SolidColorBrush;
                                IndicatorImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Images/tickMark.png"));
                                MEWSScore = "0";
                            }
                            else if (temperature <= 39)//38-39
                            {
                                TemperatureGrid.Background = (Application.Current as App).Resources["YellowObsBrush"] as SolidColorBrush;
                                IndicatorImage.Source = null;
                                MEWSScore = "1";
                                TemperatureTextBlock.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
                                MEWSScoreLabel.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
                                MEWSScoreTextBlock.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
                            }
                            else//>39
                            {
                                TemperatureGrid.Background = (Application.Current as App).Resources["AmberObsBrush"] as SolidColorBrush;
                                IndicatorImage.Source = null;
                                MEWSScore = "2";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case ObsCategories.NeurologicalObs:
                    {
                        if (CommonVariables.is_Abnormal && CommonVariables.abnormal.temperature != null)
                        {
                            if (temperature <= double.Parse(CommonVariables.abnormal.temperature.ElementAt<string>(0).Split(';').ElementAt<string>(1)))
                            {
                                TemperatureGrid.Background = (Application.Current as App).Resources["AmberObsBrush"] as SolidColorBrush;
                                IndicatorImage.Source = null;
                                MEWSScore = "2";
                            }
                            else if (temperature <= double.Parse(CommonVariables.abnormal.temperature.ElementAt<string>(1).Split(';').ElementAt<string>(1)))
                            {
                                TemperatureGrid.Background = (Application.Current as App).Resources["YellowObsBrush"] as SolidColorBrush;
                                IndicatorImage.Source = null;
                                MEWSScore = "1";
                                TemperatureTextBlock.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
                                MEWSScoreLabel.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
                                MEWSScoreTextBlock.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
                            }
                            else if (temperature <= double.Parse(CommonVariables.abnormal.temperature.ElementAt<string>(2).Split(';').ElementAt<string>(1)))
                            {
                                TemperatureGrid.Background = (Application.Current as App).Resources["GreenObsBrush"] as SolidColorBrush;
                                IndicatorImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Images/tickMark.png"));
                                MEWSScore = "0";
                            }
                            else if (temperature <= double.Parse(CommonVariables.abnormal.temperature.ElementAt<string>(3).Split(';').ElementAt<string>(1)))
                            {
                                TemperatureGrid.Background = (Application.Current as App).Resources["YellowObsBrush"] as SolidColorBrush;
                                IndicatorImage.Source = null;
                                MEWSScore = "1";
                                TemperatureTextBlock.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
                                MEWSScoreLabel.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
                                MEWSScoreTextBlock.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                TemperatureGrid.Background = (Application.Current as App).Resources["AmberObsBrush"] as SolidColorBrush;
                                IndicatorImage.Source = null;
                                MEWSScore = "2";
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {

                            if (temperature <= 35)
                            {
                                TemperatureGrid.Background = (Application.Current as App).Resources["AmberObsBrush"] as SolidColorBrush;
                                IndicatorImage.Source = null;
                                MEWSScore = "2";
                            }
                            else if (temperature <= 35.9 || (temperature <= 38.5 && temperature >= 38.1))
                            {
                                TemperatureGrid.Background = (Application.Current as App).Resources["YellowObsBrush"] as SolidColorBrush;
                                IndicatorImage.Source = null;
                                MEWSScore = "1";
                                TemperatureTextBlock.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
                                MEWSScoreLabel.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
                                MEWSScoreTextBlock.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
                            }
                            else if (temperature <= 38)//36-38
                            {
                                TemperatureGrid.Background = (Application.Current as App).Resources["GreenObsBrush"] as SolidColorBrush;
                                IndicatorImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Images/tickMark.png"));
                                MEWSScore = "0";
                            }
                            else//>=38.6
                            {
                                TemperatureGrid.Background = (Application.Current as App).Resources["AmberObsBrush"] as SolidColorBrush;
                                IndicatorImage.Source = null;
                                MEWSScore = "2";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    break;
            }
            MEWSScoreTextBlock.Text = MEWSScore;
        }

        //private void DegreesComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        //{
        //    ContinueButton.Content = "Update";

        //    DegreesTextBlock.Text = DegreesComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
        //    int selectedDegrees = Int32.Parse(DegreesComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString());

        //    if (selectedDegrees < 30) //<30
        //        BindedTemperatureSP.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGreen);
        //    else if (selectedDegrees < 70)//30 to 70
        //        BindedTemperatureSP.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
        //    else //>70
        //        BindedTemperatureSP.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
        //}

        //private void DecimalComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        //{
        //    ContinueButton.Content = "Update";
        //    DecimalTextBlock.Text = DecimalComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString();

        //}

        private void MinusButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            TemperatureSlider.Value -= TemperatureSlider.StepFrequency;
        }

        private void PlusButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            TemperatureSlider.Value += TemperatureSlider.StepFrequency;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is just a thought but, it is probably due that the value for that property changes, which fires the event, before the control is actually loaded on the screen. Instead of setting the event handler in the INIT part (TemperatureOrbsControl()), you may want to put it in a different spot, like the Rendered event or something.

Answer (score 0):

The `TemperatureSlider_ValueChanged` Event is even called when the slider got initially loaded for the first time and its value got set to zero.

You can avoid this behaviour by checking the slider's value every time the event is raised:

```
void TemperatureSlider_ValueChanged(object sender, RangeBaseValueChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (TemperatureSlider.Value != 0)
    {
        ContinueButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your event is fired, because you are changing the Slider value just after subscribing to `ValueChanged`:

```
public TemperatureObsControl()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    TemperatureSlider.ValueChanged += TemperatureSlider_ValueChanged; // here you subscribe
    TemperatureSlider.Value = 37; // here you change
    ContinueButton.Content = "No Change";
    ContinueButton.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

Check also your xaml if you hadn't added `Value=...` property to your Slider - it will also fire the Event and make your Button Visible - that can be the main problem as you are setting your Button invisible at the end of the Constructor.

Note that for your situation (changing Visibility) you can for example Bind Visibility to Silder's value via Converter.